# How create XML from webpage

Tags: php, dom, symfony

I want create a XML file from web page.I have site with for example this table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><a href="/Surgery/web/app_dev.php/workers/13/show">13</a></td>
            <td>aa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>

        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work. How to load data from table in web page  ?

```
 $currentUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
 $domOb = new \DOMDocument();
 $html = $domOb->loadHTMLFile($currentUrl);
```

I work on localhost and use Symfony2

EDIT:

I have problem after excecute this code

```
$currentUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
$domOb = new \DOMDocument();
$xml = $domOb->loadHTML(file_get_contents($currentUrl));
```

I get

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://`localhost`/Surgery/web/app_dev.php/test):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in

in php.ini I have `allow_url_fopen = On`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `loadHTML` method for `$domOb` object and pass the content of a webpage:

```
// disable libxml warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$currentUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
$domOb = new \DOMDocument();
@$domOb->loadHTML(file_get_contents($currentUrl));
```

Then you can use `$domOb` object to parse html, for example to get your table you can do following:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domOb);
$items = $xpath->evaluate("//table[contains(@class, 'table')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

And display it with a correct manner:

```
$currentUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri();
$domOb = new \DOMDocument();
$xml = $domOb->loadHTML(file_get_contents($currentUrl));
header('text/xml; charset=utf-8');
echo $xml;
```